# Convert DB file to SQL or Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, sqlite

I'd like to convert a .db file to .sql format. Even though, there are some problems. I've tried this command:  sqlite3 Zx.db .dump > ZX.sql. It has generated the sql file, but in the file I have the following:

```
  PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    /**** ERROR: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database *****/

    ROLLBACK; -- due to errors
```

I've tried to see what it is in the original file with the geditor, but then it would give me a problem with the encoding. Also, I've tried open it in the MySQL workbench, but it also give me an "Unknown file encoding". Firstly, I want to know how to open this file, what software I'd use. But mainly, I'd like to know how to convert to sql file... I know that by the comment under the "begin transaction" this file can possibly not be a database... but it was required for me to convert it to a sql file.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an SQLite db file from an android phone.  If that is the case, there's a good chance that it's encrypted and not convertable.

Comment: @pnuts, It game the following first line: FF FF 04 00  00 00 00 00  1B 88 04 00  00 04 00 00. It's interesting, cause it was shared for a freelance... how can it be encrypted?

Comment: I don't think it's encrypted. I tried to open it in LibreOffice Calculator and it worked, it read it, but in a bad format. Here is the content of one of the spread sheets: TOPDIRSUBDIRNUMDOCSTOTALPAGESTOTALSIZEdarrayINSTANCEindexdef��������d�����������������

Comment: I've tried to get the encoding of the file using the enca(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/enca.1.html), but it failed to give me this information.

Comment: I think I got what happened: the file is a ctree file, use SQL and NoSQL statements. I don't know how to open these kind of files neither how to convert it to SQL or Access... anyone can help?